# How to use robotframework to activate macOS terminal and type a command, add some delay, and then execute it?

Tags: applescript, robotframework

I am using RobotFramework as RPA. and it uses osascript.

### What i want

I want to run a `env` in the `Terminal` and wait for 3 seconds before it shows the results.

### What works

```
Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to activate'
    Sleep    1s
    Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env" in window 1'
    Sleep    5s
    Run    osascript -e 'quit app "Terminal"'
```

This works but the execution of `env` is immediate every time no matter where i put `delay 3`

### What i tried

```
Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env" in window 1'
    Run    osascript -e 'delay 3'
```

```
Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env" in window 1 delay 3'
```

```
Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env" & delay 3 in window 1'
```

```
Run    osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env"  in window 1 & delay 3'
```

None of these work.

Comment: If you do no want to see the output of the `env` _command_  for three seconds then wait  the 3 seconds before executing it. E.g.: `osascript -e 'delay 3' -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "env" in window 1'`

Comment: no i want to have the 3 second delay AFTER the command is typed but BEFORE the output is shown

Comment: The problem is obvious in that once `env` is executed its _output_ is going to immediately be shown unless you do it in such a manner, e.g.: `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to do script "foo=\"$(env)\"; sleep 3; echo \"$foo\"; unset foo" in window 1'`

Comment: Is there a way to type without executing directly? Wait then execute? Can System Events help?

Comment: If executing directly in **Terminal** then: `osascript -e 'tell app "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell app "System Events"' -e 'keystroke "env"' -e 'delay 3' -e 'keystroke return' -e 'end tell'` However, if the _window_ in **Terminal** looses focus during the 3 second delay then it fails.